# can't rebuild solution after entering a pre-build command line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have just upgraded my visual studio to the 2015 edition.

I have a solution with just two project. I can rebuild the solution and run the code fine. However I have an issue when I enter a parameter in the Properties > Build Events > Pre-build event command line.

I have simply entered the following in the text box,

```
/MTEST
```

When I try to rebuild the solution I get the error message "The command "/MTEST" exited with code 9009".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
            NormalMonring();
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                switch(args[i].ToUpper())
                {
                    case "/AUTO":
                        //code
                    case "/MTEST":
                        // code
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have done something similar to this before and not had any issues don't understand what is happening?

Comment: That looks like you want to set the Debug->Start Options->Command line arguments.

Comment: oh god yep! Thats a bit stupid of me! Thank-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-build event command line is meant for running command line programs before the build.  Like if you have something that generates code that you will then build.  If you are looking to pass that value to your console application when you debug it then you can set it in Debug->Start Options->Command line arguments.